# WSO2 API Manager (wso2am-2.1.0) - Recurring Exception javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: TopicConnectionFactory

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2am-2.1.0 and the following error is recurring in the wso2carbon.log log file. This is causing an unnecessary growth in the log files of the APIM server.
A valid solution to resolve this issue is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.core.internal.OutputAdapterRuntime} -  Event dropped at Output Adapter 'jmsEventPublisher' for tenant id '-1234', Cannot acquire JNDI context, JMS Connection factory : TopicConnectionFactory or default destinationName : throttleData for JMS CF : jmsEventPublisher using : {transport.jms.ConcurrentPublishers=allow, java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties, java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.DestinationType=topic, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=TopicConnectionFactory, transport.jms.Destination=throttleData} {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.core.internal.OutputAdapterRuntime}
org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.core.exception.OutputEventAdapterRuntimeException: Cannot acquire JNDI context, JMS Connection factory : TopicConnectionFactory or default destinationName : throttleData for JMS CF : jmsEventPublisher using : {transport.jms.ConcurrentPublishers=allow, java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties, java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.DestinationType=topic, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=TopicConnectionFactory, transport.jms.Destination=throttleData}
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.<init>(JMSConnectionFactory.java:90)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.JMSEventAdapter.initPublisher(JMSEventAdapter.java:202)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.JMSEventAdapter.connect(JMSEventAdapter.java:135)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.core.internal.OutputAdapterRuntime.publish(OutputAdapterRuntime.java:68)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.core.internal.CarbonOutputEventAdapterService.publish(CarbonOutputEventAdapterService.java:143)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.core.internal.EventPublisher.process(EventPublisher.java:425)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.core.internal.EventPublisher.sendEvent(EventPublisher.java:232)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.core.internal.EventPublisher.onEvent(EventPublisher.java:300)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.stream.core.internal.EventJunction.sendEvents(EventJunction.java:194)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.listener.SiddhiOutputStreamListener.receive(SiddhiOutputStreamListener.java:103)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.stream.output.StreamCallback.receiveEvents(StreamCallback.java:98)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.stream.output.StreamCallback.receive(StreamCallback.java:69)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.stream.StreamJunction.sendEvent(StreamJunction.java:126)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.stream.StreamJunction$Publisher.send(StreamJunction.java:323)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.output.callback.InsertIntoStreamCallback.send(InsertIntoStreamCallback.java:46)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.output.ratelimit.OutputRateLimiter.sendToCallBacks(OutputRateLimiter.java:78)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.output.ratelimit.PassThroughOutputRateLimiter.process(PassThroughOutputRateLimiter.java:40)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.selector.QuerySelector.processNoGroupBy(QuerySelector.java:123)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.selector.QuerySelector.process(QuerySelector.java:86)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttling.siddhi.extension.EmitOnStateChange.process(EmitOnStateChange.java:80)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.processor.stream.StreamProcessor.processEventChunk(StreamProcessor.java:45)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.processor.stream.AbstractStreamProcessor.process(AbstractStreamProcessor.java:101)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.input.ProcessStreamReceiver.processAndClear(ProcessStreamReceiver.java:154)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.input.ProcessStreamReceiver.process(ProcessStreamReceiver.java:80)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.input.ProcessStreamReceiver.receive(ProcessStreamReceiver.java:102)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.stream.StreamJunction.sendEvent(StreamJunction.java:126)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.stream.StreamJunction$Publisher.send(StreamJunction.java:323)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.output.callback.InsertIntoStreamCallback.send(InsertIntoStreamCallback.java:46)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.output.ratelimit.OutputRateLimiter.sendToCallBacks(OutputRateLimiter.java:78)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.output.ratelimit.PassThroughOutputRateLimiter.process(PassThroughOutputRateLimiter.java:40)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.selector.QuerySelector.processInBatchGroupBy(QuerySelector.java:253)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.selector.QuerySelector.process(QuerySelector.java:78)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.throttling.siddhi.extension.ThrottleStreamProcessor.process(ThrottleStreamProcessor.java:175)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.processor.stream.StreamProcessor.processEventChunk(StreamProcessor.java:45)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.processor.stream.AbstractStreamProcessor.process(AbstractStreamProcessor.java:101)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.input.stream.single.EntryValveProcessor.process(EntryValveProcessor.java:47)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.Scheduler$EventCaller.run(Scheduler.java:171)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: TopicConnectionFactory
        at org.wso2.andes.jndi.ReadOnlyContext.lookup(ReadOnlyContext.java:271)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSUtils.lookup(JMSUtils.java:339)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.<init>(JMSConnectionFactory.java:85)
        ... 43 more
```

Comment: Have you made any recent changes to the pack? Or are you observing this from the setup? Could you please also share how many instances of WSO2 API Manager is used and how they are deployed?

Comment: Hi @Athiththan recently no change was made. Actually this issue was there for quite some time. There are 3 nodes in the cluster and the exception is visible in all the nodes.

Comment: Can you check whether you have any configurations listed in the `jndi.properties` with the following: `connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory`

Comment: Hi @Athiththan all the lines in the jndi.properties file are commented out.

Comment: Can you try uncommenting the mentioned configuration from the `jndi.properties` and share the behaviour?